# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: illegalstateexception, mediarecorder, android-10.0

I have this function that records the screen. It works from Android 6 to 9. From Andriod 10, issues start to arrise.

```
private void initRecorder() {
    try {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        //VIDEO RATES
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); //Be very careful with the Encoder, it should match the VideoSource
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        //AUDIO RATES
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        videoUri = FilingSystem.Companion.getCompletedLectures()
                + "/" + fileName + "_Dub_Records_" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")
                .format(new Date()) +
                ".mp4";

        compressedVideo = FilingSystem.Companion.getCompletedLectures()
                + "/" + fileName + "_Compressed_Dub_Records_" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")
                .format(new Date()) +
                ".mp4";



        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTATION.get(rotation + 90);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        surface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

From the function, you can see that the mediaRecorder is already prepared. So now when I start it in the onActivityResult since I have to get a couple of permissions for this, it works for Android 6 to Android 9. But in Android 10, I get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.ynot/com.example.ynot.Activities.LectureStudio}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5589)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5630)
```